# Prove that triangle inequality holds for $d(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

I got 0 points for the proof I gave, and I would like to know the mistakes I made. 
Thank you.

Want to show: $$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \le \frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|} + \frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}$$ $$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \le \frac{|x-z|+2|x-z||z-y|+|z-y|}{(1+|x-z|)(1+|z-y|)}$$ Let $a = |x-y|, b = |x-z|, c = |z-y|$. We have already shown that $|x-y| \le |x-z|+|z-y|$ (i.e. $a \le b + c$). $$\frac{a}{1+a} \le \frac{b+2bc+c}{(1+b)(1+c)}$$ $$a (1+b+c+bc) \le (b+2bc+c)(1+a)$$ $$a+ab+ac+abc \le b+2bc+c+ab+2abc+ac$$
$$a \le b+c+2bc+abc$$, which we know is true, $\because a \le b + c$. So $d(x,y)$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

My grader wrote that if $a=1; b=c=0$ then the inequality does not hold. But if $b=c$, then $x=z=y$, and therefore $a = 0$ too.

Comment: Well, one issue with your proof is that it reads as if you've assumed the conclusion you wanted to prove, and deduced from that the premise you were meant to take as given. A correct proof would emphasise (and ideally show) the equivalence of the steps you tried to take.

Comment: Any other critiques? I would very much like to know how I can improve. I'm new to proofs. In other words, what would be a stronger way of starting it?

Comment: Actually, had you written your proof _backwards_ it seems like this would be a completely valid proof. That is, assuming every step you've taken is correct -- I haven't actually checked to make sure.

Comment: `a ≤ b+c+2bc` That's missing a term on the RHS, though that doesn't change much there. That said, I agree with the previous comment that the major objection is most likely about writing it as a sequence of implications without making it plenty clear that all steps are in fact "reversible" equivalences.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm having difficulties understanding about the 'reverse'. Could you perhaps elucidate a bit more, or how you would start writing the reversal of this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Begin your proof with: Let $a,b$ and $c$ be non-negative and let $a\le b+c$. Then it follows that $a\le b+c+2bc$. Then proceed to the remaining inequalities in $a,b$ and $c$. At that point, make the substitutions in $x,y$ and $z$ and finish with the inequality you wished to prove.

Comment: @zodross Too long for a comment, posted as an answer. `reversible` simply means that an equivalence is an implication that works both ways, so you can read the steps from start to end, or "reverse" the steps from end to start, and it's a valid deduction either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is OP's proof plus my annotations (in red), which would make it rigorous IMHO.

> Want to show:
>   $$
> \color{red}{d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)} \tag{1}
> $$
>   $$
> \color{red}{\iff\quad}\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \le \frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|} + \frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}
> $$
>   $$
> \color{red}{\iff\quad}\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \le \frac{|x-z|+2|x-z||z-y|+|z-y|}{(1+|x-z|)(1+|z-y|)} \tag{2}
> $$
>
> Let $\,a = |x-y|, \,b = |x-z|, \,c = |z-y|\, \color{red}{\;\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{where}}\; a,b,c \ge 0 \;\;\;(3)\,}\,$.
>   
>   We have already shown that $|x-y| \le |x-z|+|z-y|$  <s>i.e.</s>  $\;\color{red}{\iff}a \le b + c \;\;\;\color{red}{(4)}\,$.
>   
>   $\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Then}}\; (2)} \;\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{can be rewritten in terms of}}\; a,b,c \;\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{as follows}}}\,$:
>
> $$\frac{a}{1+a} \le \frac{b+2bc+c}{(1+b)(1+c)} \tag{5}$$
>
> $\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{The denominators are positive on both sides because of}}\;(3) ,\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{and after eliminating them}}:}$
>
> $$a (1+b+c+bc) \le (b+2bc+c)(1+a)$$
>   $$\color{red}{\iff\quad}a+ab+ac+abc \le b+2bc+c+ab+2abc+ac$$
>   $$\color{red}{\iff\quad}a \le b+c+2bc \color{red}{+abc} \tag{6}$$
>
> which we know is true $\because a \le b + c$ $\,\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{by}}\;(4)}\,$.
>
> $\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Since we proved}}\;(6)\;\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{to hold true,}}}$ $\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{and all steps from}}\;(1)\; \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{to}} \;(6)\;}$ $\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{are reversible equivalences,}}}$ $\color{red}{\style{font-family:inherit}{\text{the above proves}}\;(1)}\,$. So $d(x,y)$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

As a side comment, `my grader wrote that if a=1, b=c=0 then the inequality does not hold` their choice of values is inconsistent with $\,(4)\,$ so it cannot be used as a counterexample to dispute or invalidate the proof.

As for `I would very much like to know how I can improve` one way would be to write your own version of the above (note: do *not* copy/paste, make it your *own* proof), and ask the grader what they think about it. That should give you a better sense of what the requirements/expectations are.

Comment: I never copy/paste, if I don't try to do it myself what is the point of me trying to better myself and get a degree in mathematics. Thank you for your input. Unfortunately I do not have my grader's contacts. and when I went to ask my professor, they had told me that 'a,b,c' was arbitrary and my inequality is not always true. I did not understand how, and was embarrassed to ask further as they seemed that it was simple why it was wrong. Though I very much appreciate the time and effort you've spent to show all the holes that my proof was missing.

Comment: Glad it helped. `they had told me that 'a,b,c' was arbitrary and my inequality is not always true` This doesn't make sense to me, unless maybe the problem explicitly asked to *not* use the usual triangle inequality in the proof.

Comment: Here is the question verbatim:
Prove that $d(x, y) = \frac{|x − y|}
{1 + |x − y|}$
is a metric on R.

Comment: Also, I would very much like to give this a correct answer, but I am unsure if someone else might point something out. I am not doubting you. Can comments still be made after an answer is declared?

Comment: @zodross Assuming you already knew (and were allowed to use) that $\,|x-y|\,$ is a metric on $\,\Bbb R\,$, and you first checked the other properties of this metric (trivial, here), the idea of your proof was essentially right, and I don't understand their objection. Maybe someone else has a better clue about that.

Comment: P.S. Comments can always be made (unless the question is closed), and acceptance votes can be reassigned at any time.

Comment: You are right. They had said in class that first 3 properties are trivial to prove. And we had shown $|x-y|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$. It was one of the first things we covered.